# How can i have a fade effect on the bottom of the div?

Tags: css

I need to set a fade effect at the bottom of the div as in the image. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a pseudo element on your main container to achieve the desired effect.

Something like so,

html:

```
<div class="mainCont">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.mainCont {
    position: relative;
}

.mainCont:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(150, 123, 19, 1);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0% 0% 100%, from(rgba(150, 123, 19, 0.1)), to(rgba(150, 123, 19, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(150, 123, 19, 0), rgba(150, 123, 19, 1));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(150, 123, 19, 0), rgba(150, 123, 19, 1));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(150, 123, 19, 0), rgba(150, 123, 19, 1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(150, 123, 19, 0), rgba(150, 123, 19, 1));
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Finally a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79ah3/4/)

Fiddle with more content in `.mainCont`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79ah3/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.divClass {
    box-shadow: 0 80px 80px gold inset;
}
```

or

```
.anotherDivClass {
    box-shadow: 0 0 80px gold;
}
```

Depends on which element you put it on. The inset goes inside the box. Without the inset, it goes outside the box.

Comment: it works but the content generated within the div is a dynamic one and is shown above the shadow. Shadow is hiding behind the content.

Comment: @AbuIsaac You can try the second way i have. So if you have a footer, you can put the box shadow on there, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve this using `-webkit-mask-image`

```
.panel {
  width: '200px';
  height: '500px';
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    white,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
  );
}
```